# OSX C++ Clang Linker Command Error when trying to separate .cpp and .h files into different directories in a simple program

Tags: macos, clang, linker-errors

I'm learning c++ (on osx) and am trying to start to separate the .cpp files and their headers in my projects into different directories. I tried to do a test example to make sure I'm doing everything right... but apparently not. I'm using CodeRunner to write the program.

This program compiles when all of the files are in the same directory, but as soon as I try to put them in different directories, I get linker errors for the clang compiler.

File Structure:
|--main.cpp
+--header
| +--FooBar.h
+--cpp
| +--FooBar.cpp

main.cpp

```
#include <iostream>
#include "header/FooBar.h"

using namespace std;

int main(){
    FooBar instance;
    cout << instance.number;
    return 0;
}
```

FooBar.h

```
#ifndef _FooBar_h_
#define _FooBar_h_

class FooBar{
    public:
        FooBar();
        int number;
};

#endif
```

FooBar.cpp

```
#include "../header/FooBar.h"

FooBar::FooBar(){
    number = 5;
}
```

Error Message (from main.cpp)

```
Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64:
  "FooBar::FooBar()", referenced from:
      _main in main-c0378e.o
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture x86_64
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
```

I've spent multiple hours trying to find a solution to this, so asking here really is a last resort for me.

Comment: Please show you makefile as well.

Comment: Maybe that is the problem. I haven't learned about makefiles yet. I thought I could just change the #include lines to match the new directories and then everything would work fine.

Comment: How did you compile it? Looks like you compiled main.cpp but not FooBar.cpp. Therefore the linker cannot find the symbols from Foobar. You command probably just needs to list both .cpp files.

Comment: Seems so. You need to generate two obj-files and link them at the end to an executable. If not you get the error you showed us.